# julia - Better way to wait on @async loop

Tags: julia

This async loop will immediately go to the next line.

What is the best way to wait when there is no need for a condition?

```
@async while true
    sleep(1)
end

# Must be async or first loop will never get a chance to run
@async start_server_loop()

exit = Condition()
wait(exit)
```

Comment: it is not clear when you want to exit. Do you want to make sure that loop 1 run at least once? what is modiftying the `Condition`.  It is not possible to answer this question without more details.

Comment: I just want to wait forever while letting the other loops do their thing.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your goal is as in the comment "I just want to wait forever while letting the other loops do their thing":

```
@sync begin

  @async do_loop1()
  @async do_loop2()
  @async do_loop3()

end
```

Note that this code is only useful when the loops block on I/O. If the loops are CPU-intensive you should use threads instead.

Comment: Julia does not expose the notion of threads to the user. `Threads.@spawn` is still creating tasks (yes I know big misnomer).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to suspend the root-task.

Just `wait()` will do that.

> If no argument is passed, the task blocks for an undefined period. A task
> can only be restarted by an explicit call to schedule or yieldto.

Alternatively you could call `start_server_loop()` and execute that on the root-task itself. (Or `wait(@async start_server_loop())`)

> `# Must be async or first loop will never get a chance to run`

This sounds like you are running into another issue. Julia is using cooperative tasking. That means the runtime **will not** interrupt a task, while it is running. So your `start_server_loop()` or your `while true; ...; end` loop need an explicit call to `yield()` in order to give other tasks time to run.

Lastly I would recommend using `Threads.@spawn` so that you can use multiple worker threads to execute your tasks. `@async` will execute the code on the same thread it was spawned from.

Comment: Great answer, thank you.  Just to clarify, if using Threads.@spawn you don't need to yield to anyone?  Also, this is only true when using multiple low-level system threads?